# swift - Nav Bar disappears after leaving screen then returning

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I start of my app in `NewHomePageVC` ( `NewHomePageVc` is a programmatically made VC) and its shows the navigation bar then I hit logout go to `SignInVc` (`SigninVC` was made with storyboard and is a `UITableviewController`) and log back in and it returns to `NewHomePageVC` but this time there is no navigation bar?

**In AppDelegate:**

```
  FIRApp.configure()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: NewHomePageVC())

    return true
```

**In NewHomePageVC:**

```
import UIKit

class NewHomePageVC: UITableViewController{

    var signInVC: SignInVC?
    var userScreenVC: usersScreenVC?
    var chatLogController: ChatLogController?
    var NewHomePage_Vc: NewHomePageVC?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    func SetUpNavBarButtons(){

    }

    func SetUpNavBarButtons(){

        // navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))

        let logOutButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))

        let toUserScreenGrape = UIImage(named: "Grape Small Image")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        let toUserScreenGrapeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: toUserScreenGrape, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(didTapUserScreenButton))

        let buttonsRight : NSArray = [toUserScreenGrapeButton]

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttonsRight as? [UIBarButtonItem]
    }

    func didTapUserScreenButton() {
        let user_screen_vc = usersScreenVC()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: user_screen_vc)
        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have implemented methods in viewDidLoad().

Comment: @devang bhatt why? if i  don't then it doesn't load in the view, also do you know the answer to the question? on why the nav bar would be there and then would not be there upon returning the the view controller?

Comment: Ya but you should implement your methods outside of viewDidLoad() and then call it in viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being inside of `SignInVC`

I changed

```
self.present(NewHomePage_VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to

```
let editorViewController = NewHomePageVC()
let navEditorViewController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: editorViewController)

self.present(navEditorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```